# How can I set a lifespan for a projectile?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class ProjectileFlightTimeUntilDecay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float PlayerProjectile;
    public float timeUntilDecay = 5.0f;

    void Start()
    {
        timeUntilDecay = timeUntilDecay * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(timeUntilDecay <= 0)
        {
            // Destroy the projectile
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this, and doesn't work.

Comment: Shouldn't you be updating `timeUntilDecay` in `Update`?

Comment: This is a low quality question for several reasons. 1. It's missing the Unity3d tag. 2. "It doesn't work" is very vague. What are you expecting to happen? What actually happened? 3. It's mostly code, with no explanation of how the code is used or what it's for.

Comment: Or you could destroy the object in start with its life timr as the delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timeUntilDecay` is never decreased from its initial value, so the check `if (timeUntilDecay <= 0)` will never be true.

Typically this is done by decrementing it in `Update()`, e.g.

```
timeUntilDecay -= Time.deltaTime;
```